# All editing and sharing options disabled in Quicktime

Tags: quicktime

I downloaded a video with these specs:

[image]

I'm unable to cut, copy, paste, trim and share since all these options are greyed out:

[image]
[image]

Why?

Comment: Paid (pro) edition vs free version?

Comment: Free version, but all these features are usually enabled and working. Re-encoded the video with Handbrake and now it works: question still standing though.

Comment: almost 5 years later, this still seems to be a thing. I used Catalina's built-in screen recording (command+shift+5) to capture two videos. Both show as 1440x1080, H.264, HD (1-1-1) colour profile. The first (3m17s) is editable, the second (11m0s) is not.